# Cannot change permissions on /System/Library

Tags: finder, macos, permission

I am running OS X 10.11.8. I am attempting to change some settings in `/Library/Filters/`. I am logged in as an administrator (verified in System Preferences > Users & Groups). When I go to Finder > Get Info for `/System/Library/`, I am able to click the unlock icon, and my password is accepted.

However, when I try to change the permission for "everyone," I get the following error:

> The operation can’t be completed because you don’t have the necessary permission.

[image]

How can I resolve this?

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899

Comment: I've looked at this, but am not sure it applies. From the article "Paths and apps that third-party apps and installers can continue to write to include: ... /Library..." Thus, SIP shouldn't affect the library folder.

Comment: Your screenshot isn’t from Library - it is from the System folder.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize there was also a top-level /Library folder. I have updated my question.

Comment: Library/Filters/ & System/Library are no proper paths. It's unclear whether /System/Library/Filters/  or /Library/Filters/ is meant.

Comment: Yes /System is locked under SIP - you can however disable SIP, if you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is no longer possible to change permissions on `/System/Library` in macOS Monterey or up.

If you're on an older version of macOS, you'll need to disable System Integrity Protection to make changes to permissions in /System.

> To disable System Integrity Protection, you can do the following:
>
> 1. Boot into the Recovery HD by restarting whilst holding ⌘R.
> 2. Open Terminal (from the Utilities menu).
> 3. Run the following command in Terminal:
>
>    ```
>     csrutil disable
>    ```
> 4. Restart.

[Disable OS X El Capitan Rootless and permit write actions to System Integrity Protection locations](https://georgegarside.com/blog/osx/package-incompatible-installer/)

Comment: Isn't this overkill?

Comment: @Pacerier How so? If one needs to make changes to /System, this is the standard way. It's not generally recommended to make changes to /System, yet this question wants to. The question may be an XY problem, but that is something to discuss regarding the question rather than this answer?

Comment: Using Monterey this doesn’t work any more. Still denying :(